# Is it possible to show progress bar in notification area when using WorkManager - Like WhatsApp data sync

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Currently, if our device connected to WiFi, WhatsApp will perform sync to cloud, by showing a progress bar in notification area.

[image]

I was wondering, how can I achieve so using `WorkManager`? Currently, I know I can setup specific constraint, for `WorkManager` to run a background job.

1. Delayed time
2. Network constraint

But, how can we show a notification UI, via `WorkManager`?

Comment: This is an ongoing notification . `NotificationCompat.Builder` has method `#setProgress` which you can use .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54602888/72437 Does that helps to move the background task to foreground task?

Comment: I don't think so . Well I do not have much experience with work manager so I can not make any specific comments on this .

Answer (score 1):

Here is something which i have in my mind that can help. 
The idea is to create a worker and put your logic to get the progress and show updates as a notification using handler.

**NOTE :** This code is not tested and i am using it just to explain the way

Worker Code

```
public class CompressWorker extends Worker {

public CompressWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
    super(context, params);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
   ProgressManager manager = new ProgressManager();
   int i = 0;
   while(i<100){
       i++;
       try {
           Thread.sleep(1000);
           manager.updateProgress(i);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
    Log.i("Ansh", "worker's job is finished");
    // Indicate success or failure with your return value:
    return Result.success();

    // (Returning Result.retry() tells WorkManager to try this task again
    // later; Result.failure() says not to try again.)
}}
```

And there is another class using the handler to send the updates to the notification

```
public class ProgressManager {

Context context;
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context);
        notificationBuilder.setProgress(100, msg.arg1, true);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(1000, notification);
    }
};


public void updateProgress(int val) {
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.arg1 = val;
    handler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 1000);
}}
```